# Why we need to worry about endianness if we are working in application level?

Tags: endianness

Do we really need to worry about endianness, if we are working on application level which doesn't involve communicating with other machine?

Comment: Do you save to files?

Comment: Yes. We are writing some data to files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endianness is also an issue when reading files.  All good file formats specify which endianness they are using when writing numbers directly.  This is one reason that some people prefer non-binary formats.